# Divrei Torah- women with uncovered hair

Tags: contemporary-halacha, kiruv-outreach

I know the Chazon Ish permits saying divrei Torah in front of women with uncovered hair if the purpose of the speech is to be Mekarev them. Does anyone know if this heter can be extended to a standard speech (bar mitzva etc) when the purpose of the speech is not at all to bring them closer to Hashem?

Comment: *when the purpose of the speech is not at all to bring them closer to hashem* - what is it for then?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: How do you know the chazon ish permits that?

Comment: Of course according to the Aruch HaShulchan and the Igros Moshe, it's mutar in general; you're just asking according to the Chazon Ish ... though sources on what he actually held would be helpful.

Comment: Chazon Ish:    https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14336&st=&pgnum=52    See top of Second column.